# select firsts closest to date rows

Tags: postgresql

How for this table x:

```
pk - uid  | post_id | date - timestamp | likes
1            1             01.01.2020      1
2            1             01.01.2021      5            
3            2             01.01.2020      1
4            4             01.01.2021      3
5            4             01.01.2022      5
6            4             01.01.2023      10
```

Using two dates (range):

```
const [start_date, end_date] = ['01.01.2021', '01.01.2022']
```

Get rows in time range (one for each post_id), closest to `start_date`

```
pk - uid  | post_id | date - timestamp | likes
2            1             01.01.2021      5            
4            4             01.01.2021      3
```

and `end_date` (separate query):

```
pk - uid  | post_id | date - timestamp | likes
2            1             01.01.2021      5            
3            2             01.01.2020      1
5            4             01.01.2022      5
```

I was traying to do it like this, but got duplicate post_id's:

```
SELECT uid, post_id, like
        FROM x
        WHERE date <= ${end_date}
        GROUP BY uid, post_uid
        ORDER BY date DESC
```

---

Bonus question - i can do this using js, with 2 result arrays above, but maybe i can get result that will be difference of end_date rows likes - start date rows:

```
pk - uid  | post_id | likes
2            1         0            
4            4         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions `first_value()` and `last_value()` to accomplish this:

```
select distinct first_value(uid) over w as uid, post_id,
       first_value(likes) over w as oldest_likes,
       last_value(likes) over w as newest_likes,
       last_value(likes) over w - first_value(likes) over w as likes
  from x
 where ddate between '2021-01-01' and '2022-01-01'
window w as (partition by post_id 
                 order by ddate 
          rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
;

 uid | post_id | oldest_likes | newest_likes | likes 
-----+---------+--------------+--------------+-------
   2 |       1 |            5 |            5 |     0
   4 |       4 |            3 |            5 |     2
(2 rows)
```